# Fetching words based on pattern from strings using regex in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the entities and columns from source data using regex in pandas column.

Data Pattern: entity.attribute

```py
Source Data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': [" if ENT_A.COL_A <> NULL then 55787-3 Then abcd.col_b derivation trf , Else NULL   EF_kl.COL_d is populated"]})
```

Code used:

```py
df['txt'].str.findall(r'\w+.\w+').str.join(", ")
```

Required Output:

```
ENT_A.COL_A,abcd.col_b,EF_kl.COL_d
```

Answer (score 0):

It remains to escape the `.` char in regex pattern:

```
df['txt'].str.findall(r'\w+\.\w+').str.join(',')
```

---

```
Out[294]: 
0    ENT_A.COL_A,abcd.col_b,EF_kl.COL_d
Name: txt, dtype: object
```